# Formulae for calculating the shape of feature maps after convolutions

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I know that Pytorch's documentation provides this, but I have difficulties in understanding their notation.

Is there any more accessible explanation (maybe also with graphical illustrations)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Receptive Field Arithmetics](https://blog.mlreview.com/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807).
This webpage provides a detailed explanation of the various factors affecting the size of the receptive field, and the shape of the resulting feature maps.